# Submit user choice radio button values where the values are defined from json

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to insert radio button values to mySql database using angular. The form cointains radio buttons and those radio button values already defined in a json file. Here is how the json file looks like:

```js
//data.json

[{
  "surveyid": 101,
  "surveyname": "Vitamin",
  "createdby": "Dr. Sarah",
  "createddate": "16-01-2018",
  "question": [{
      "questionid": 1,
      "questiondesc": "Q-1?",
      "qno": 1,
      "alloptions": [{
          "options": "A",
          "answer": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "options": "B",
          "answer": "No"
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "questionid": 2,
      "questiondesc": "Q_2?",
      "qno": 2,
      "alloptions": [{
          "options": "A",
          "answer": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "options": "B",
          "answer": "No"
        },
        {
          "options": "C",
          "answer": "Don't know"
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "questionid": 3,
      "questiondesc": "Q_3",
      "qno": 1,
      "alloptions": [{
          "options": "A",
          "answer": "Yes"
        },
        {
          "options": "B",
          "answer": "No"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

I also made a function for server side like this:

```js
app.post('/newPush', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'INSERT INTO results(question1, question2, question3)values("' + req.body.question1 + '", "' + req.body.question2 + '", "' + req.body.question3 + '")';
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(result);
    res.send('success');
  })
})
```

In the client side. I made a insert function but looks like i'm doing it wrong. I declared 3 variables and the data type is `string`.

```js
//service.ts
pushing(question1: string, question2: string, question3: string) {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/newPush', {
    question1: question1,
    question2: question2,
    question3: question3
  });
}

//component.ts
pushing(question1: string, question2: string, question3: string) {
  this.AppService.pushing(question1, question2, question3);
}
```

And for the html binding, it looks like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="isVerified" align="left" class="container">
  <form>
    <div *ngFor="let items of jsonData">
      <div *ngFor="let items2 of items.question">
        <label>{{items2.questionid}}. {{items2.questiondesc}}</label>
        <div *ngFor="let items3 of items2.alloptions; let i=index">
          <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question{{items2.questionid}}" value="{{items3.answer}}"><b>{{items3.options}}</b>. {{items3.answer}}
          </div>
        </div><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="pushing(question1, question2, question3)">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm not sure where i'm doing it wrong (the server side or the client side). Can anyone help me, please? Please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your template looks incorrect. Use the below:

```
<div *ngIf="isVerified" align="left" class="container">
  <form>
    <div *ngFor="let items of jsonData; let counter = index;">
      <div *ngFor="let items2 of items.question">
        <label>{{items2.questionid}}. {{items2.questiondesc}}</label>
        <div *ngFor="let items3 of items2.alloptions; let i=index">
          <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question{{items2.questionid}}_option{{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]='answers[counter ]' value="{{items3.answer}}"><b>{{items3.options}}</b>. {{items3.answer}}
          </div>
        </div><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="pushing(answers[0], answers[1], answers[2])">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In your componet file, declare the array of answers as follows:

```
answers: string[] = ['','',''];
```

This way your answers will be selected through ngModel, which is the right way to get the value of form fields in Angular.

Comment: share the plunk.